# Authenticating with LDAP

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ldap

I want to connect LDAP to my MariaDB instance on my Ubuntu server so that I can create user accounts by linking them like this:

```
CREATE USER 'testuser'@'%'
  IDENTIFIED WITH authentication_ldap_simple
  AS 'uid=testuser,ou=testing,dc=test,dc=com';
```

But for that I need to install the plugin `authentication_ldap_simple`. I tried installing it with this command but it failed:

```
INSTALL PLUGIN authentication_ldap_simple SONAME 'authentication_ldap_simple.so';
ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/authentication_ldap_simple.so' (errno: 2, cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

I tried to find a way to install the plugin via apt but I couldn't find any. Can you help me? How do I install `authentication_ldap_simple` or get the file `authentication_ldap_simple.so`? Or is there another way to authenticate with LDAP?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates `errno: 2, cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. I believe your .so is either broken/corrupt or is fetching from incorrect path. The plugin should be present in `/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/`. Validate if MySQL is trying to install the plugin from above path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, mariadb is trying to install it from /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ but the file isn't existing. I've searched the whole system using `find` and it doesn't exist. Do you know how I can get the file?

Comment: If you have another set up, just copy the .so file.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have another setup. Do you know from where I could download the .so file by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

'authentication_ldap_simple' is library in Mysql enterprise edition